# Meaning of "chkconfig" runlevels "S" (capital S) and "B" (capital B) in Linux

Tags: linux, sles, chkconfig, runlevel

I'm running the `chkconfig --list` command on a server with SLES 10 SP2 (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10 Service Pack 2). I know the meaning of runlevels from 0 to 6, but some lines also have a "**S**" (uppercase S) and one line has a "**B**" (uppercase B).

Let me quote here a snipped output of "`chkconfig --list`" - note that, on one hand, the "`kbd`", "`microcode`", "`splash`", "`splash_early`" lines have the "`S:on`" at the end of the line **and** that, on the other hand, the "`sysstat`" line finishes with "`B:on`":

```
# chkconfig --list
(...)
dbus                      0:off  1:off  2:off  3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
(...)
kbd                       0:off  1:on   2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off  S:on
(...)
microcode                 0:off  1:on   2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off  S:on
(...)
splash                    0:off  1:on   2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off  S:on
splash_early              0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
(...)
syslog                    0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
sysstat                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off  B:on
(...)
```

I have read the Serverfault Question & Answer [Explanation of chkconfig Levels](https://serverfault.com/questions/356984/explanation-of-chkconfig-levels) but the only Answer there mentions the runlevels 0 to 6 only.

The manpage for chkconfig in this machine also only mentions runlevels zero to six:

```
# man chkconfig

(...)

LIST MODE
   List mode prints for each specified service a line that consists of the 
   service name and for runlevels zero to six  **on** or **off** depending if the
   service will be started or not.  **on** will be printed in bright green 
   if the output is written to a terminal. If the --deps option is given, 
   the names of the services  that  must  be  started before this service is 
   appended to each line. The inetd/xinetd services are listed in extra
   sections.
(...)
```

So, my question is: what is / could be the meaning of the "**S**" and "**B**" in the `chkconfig --list` output **?**

(I'm guessing that "S" might be "Startup" and that "B" could be "Boot" but I'm not finding any related documentation or web page that addresses this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runlevel B is SUSE specific. It means "boot". It is intended for software that should run during the boot sequence, before
the system enters one of the "real" runlevels. "S" is a single user mode as runelevel 1.